# функция для Telegram бота

Tags: python, telebot

Помогите решить задачу. Задание: написать функцию,которая принимает на вход текст сообщения  например «Сообщение», и отправляет его вам в Telegram.

```
Импортируйте пакеты библиотеки python-telegram-bot.
Создайте экземпляр класса telegram.Bot, он будет интерфейсом между вашим кодом и Bot API.
Вызовите в коде функцию send_message().
```

Токен передаётся в конструктор класса telegram.Bot при создании экземпляра.
Импортируйте пакеты командой import telegram.
Для отправки сообщения вам нужен метод telegram.Bot.send_message. **Передайте в него chat_id и text. Меня хватило только на это:

```
import telegram
from telegram import Bot


TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'здесь у меня токен'  # Добавьте токен в код
CHAT_ID = 'здесь айди'  # Укажите chat_id

bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

def send_text(message):
    if message.text() == 'Сообщение':
        bot.send_message(message.chat_id)
    
def send_message(message):
    chat_id = CHAT_ID
    text = self.message
    bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging, telegram
from time import sleep
from telegram.error import NetworkError, Unauthorized
UPDATE_ID = None
def echo(bot):
    global UPDATE_ID
    for update in bot.get_updates(offset=UPDATE_ID, timeout=10):
        UPDATE_ID = update.update_id + 1
        if update.message: if update.message.text: update.message.reply_text(f'{update.message.text}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global UPDATE_ID
    bot = telegram.Bot('TOKEN')
    try: UPDATE_ID = bot.get_updates()[0].update_id
    except IndexError: UPDATE_ID = None
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    while True:
        try: echo(bot)
        except Unauthorized: UPDATE_ID += 1
```

Comment: Стоит это добавить к ранее данному ответу, а не давать отдельный ответ.

Comment: Код рабочий, но тренажер его не принимает(( Слишком большой код.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать комментарии и отступы. Если будет время то я его сокращу

Comment: Вот я немного укоротил код!

Answer (score 0):

```html
import telegram
from telegram import Bot

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'здесь у меня токен'  # Добавьте токен в код
CHAT_ID = 'здесь айди'  # Укажите chat_id

bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

def send_text(message):
    text = message.text
    if text == 'Сообщение':
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        bot.send_message(chat_id, text)

def send_message(message):
    chat_id = CHAT_ID
    text = message
    bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]